# Rotating the Sides of a Quadrilateral Rotates its Diagonals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

**Rotating the 4 sides:** 
Given ABCD, **rotate AB** by $\theta$ to get A'B', and **rotate CD** by $\theta$ to get C'D'.

*(When we speak of rotating a segment by $\theta$, we mean rotating it by an angle of $\theta$, counter-clockwise around its midpoint.)*

Then rotate the other two sides:  **rotate B'C'** by $\theta$ to get B''C'', and **rotate D'A'** by $\theta$ to get D''A''.

**To Prove:**

The diagonals have rotated: (but not around their midpoints)
**Theorem 1:** Diagonal A''C'' is at an angle of $\theta$ from AC.
(And similarly for B''D'' and BD.)

They are rotating around a point on the line: 
**Theorem 2:** The point A''C'' $\cap$ AC is independent of $\theta$.

**Theorem 3:** If the diagonals were perpendicular at P, then the new diagonals are also perpendicular at P.

---

**Comments:** 
I have a proof but it is a mess of coordinates and trigonometry, completely unenlightening.

I would like a geometrical proof.

Rotation is such a simple operation to do, I am surprised I have never heard of any theorem like this.

Comment: Please include some salient aspects of your proof. This could save people from duplicating your effort.

Comment: @Blue: As I said, my proof involved expressing coordinates of points via trig functions. It was a mess, and it is irrelevant to what I am asking for. I would like to see a synthetic proof that is not based on coordinates, and preferably not on trigonometry. Additionally, I do not share your fear of duplicated effort! If people want to prove these theorems via coordinates, that's ok, it's just not what I'm asking for here. If you want someone to type up an algebraic proof, don't worry, in my experience people will submit such answers here anyway, regardless of what I say I am looking for. ;-)

Comment: You might find your coordinate/trigonometric work unenlightening and irrelevant, but others might find guidance in it. Be that as it may ... Are there any insights from your working of the problem that you can share? For instance, can you say something about the locations of the fixed points $\overline{A''C''}\cap\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{B''D''}\cap\overline{BD}$? It's can be helpful to know exactly what we're looking-for here.

Comment: @Blue: With a,b,c,d ∈ ℝ, set A=2a, B=2ib, C=-2c, D=-2id, e^iθ=x. Then A',B' = (a+ib)±x(a-ib) and C',D' = -(c+id)∓x(c-id). So 2B'' = [(a+ib)-x(a-ib)-(c+id)-x(c-id)]+x[(a+ib)-x(a-ib)+(c+id)+x(c-id)] = (a-c)uv+ibuu-idvv, where u,v=1±x. Since |x|=1, we have u⊥v, so uu || vv ⊥ uv, with angle independent of a,b,c,d. So B'' has argument π/2+θ. This proves theorem 3, which I found first. Then I tried non-⟂ diagonals, and saw that the rotation stayed constant (theorem 1), but the crossing point moved around. But it moves in a steady circle, which in light of theorem 1 is equivalent to theorem 2.